# how to profile application startup with visualvm

Tags: java, profiling, visualvm

As far as i can tell, [you can only profile a running application using VisualVM](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/guides/visualvm/applications_local.html).

Does anyone know of a way to profile the launch and startup of a java application using VisualVM?

I'm convinced there must be a way, otherwise it would be a major oversight.

Hoping I've just misread the documentation.

Thanks, p.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Are you setting up the profiling using the `-Xrunjdwp" command-line option? If so, that option has a ["suspend" parameter](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/guides/jpda/conninv.html#Connectors) for just this purpose:

> True if the target VM is to be suspended immediately before the main class is loaded; false otherwise.

Example from my own config:

```
-Xrunjdwp:transport=dt_socket,address=8000,server=y,suspend=n
```

I use this with the YourKit profiler, but I think the principle is the same.

Comment: i am not using the Xrunjdwp option, should i be? the default value for suspend is 'true', isn't that correct?

Comment: @pstanton: I'm not really sure about the whats-and-wheres of `Xrunjdwp`. I suggest reading up on it, see if you can use it.

Comment: @pstanton: What is the exact -Xrunjdwp command you ended up using? When I try to use it with VisualVM, VisualVM is no longer able to properly connect to the JVM process.

Comment: sorry jim, i gave up. i actually wrote some code so that my program paused until a button was clicked .. which i'd click after i'd attached the profiler ;)

Comment: However, answers elsewhere claim that `-Xrunjdwp` does not help. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7096121/profile-entire-java-program-execution-in-visualvm

Comment: the `jdwp` in `-Xrunjdwp` stands for **Java Debug Wire Protocol**. Notice the word **Debug**

Answer (score 19):

Use the eclipse launcher, and set a breakpoint at an appropriate place in the main method.

Then, start in debug mode, enable profiling in visualVM, and then resume using eclipse.

That won't profile class loading and stuff, but it's good enough for me.

Answer (score 10):

I found [Startup Profiler](https://visualvm.github.io/startupprofiler.html) helpful:

> Startup Profiler plugin for VisualVM 1.3.6 enables instrumented
>   profiling of local Java 5+ applications from their startup. It is also
>   helpful when profiling short-running processes.

Comment: This ended up working for me, but make sure you download the separate VisualVM application and don't try to reuse the one that comes with the JDK; for some reason, the Startup Profiler plugin isn't available for the stock JDK version.

Answer (score 0):

Both common Java development environments (NetBeans/Eclipse) support application execution directly with attached VisualVM. In case of Eclipse you have to install a [plugin](https://visualvm.dev.java.net/eclipse-launcher.html). In case of NetBeans the support is AFAIK already integrated.
Even if do not have the sources you can still run the JAR file(s) via both environments and therefore start your app connected with VisualVM.

Comment: the eclipse plugin does not assist with this. it just launches VVM when you start a process.