# Can I suspend Java runtime on method entry to have time to attach by debugger or profiler?

Tags: java, debugging, jvm, profiling, remote-debugging

Is there a way to suspend all business-logic execution threads of Java process when execution hits some method?

If  it is not possible via external configuration is there any method call to embedd into application to achieve desired result?

Comment: You might use Object.wait, or Thread.sleep(ms). Each work on the current executing thread. Oh wait, I suspect you cannot modify the source code, right?

Comment: You mean you want to wait before attaching a debugger, instead of having the debugger attached and waiting for it to hit a breakpoint?

Comment: I cannot run application from debugger/profiler but can attach to process. `Thread.sleep` is not productive solution.

Comment: Then attach to a process. Set a breakpoint and you're ready to go. No need for any weird tricks you were thinking about.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

According to [how to profile application startup with visualvm](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4434860/how-to-profile-application-startup-with-visualvm) I can start application with

```
-Xrunjdwp:transport=dt_socket,address=8000,server=y,suspend=y
```

to stop execution on app startup.

May be it would be possible to set breakpoint and move to interesting app state and then attach with profiler and start app again.

Another option is to start with Java agent: https://visualvm.github.io/startupprofiler.html

Answer (score 2):

One solution is the place this code right before the method you want to debug:

`System.out.println("Press Any Key To Continue...");
new java.util.Scanner(System.in).nextLine();`

This waits until you press enter, so you have time to attach your debugger.

Another method is to use the IDE Netbeans, which contains a debugger and allows you to set breakpoints anywhere.

Comment: I can start Java process with `-agentlib:jdwp=transport=dt_socket,server=y,address=8000,suspend=y`. But can other tools attach to this process for instrumentation?

Comment: @gavenkoa that's the whole point. Have you tried connecting there with a debugger?